# WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent and gevent-websocket for improved performance

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io

В моем приложении используется flask_socketio, вот так я его запускаю:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Configuration)

socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

@socketio.on("join-room")
def join_room_handler(roomId, newUserId):
  emit("user-connected", newUserId, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

В ответ получаю записи в консоли:

```
> python.exe .\run.py
WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent 
and gevent-websocket for improved performance.
 * Serving Flask app "app.entry_point" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent 
and gevent-websocket for improved performance.
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 292-577-953
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Меня смущает сообщение:

```
WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent 
and gevent-websocket for improved performance.
```

**Важно**: Все работает, как я хочу, приложение запускается и делает то, что мне нужно.

Когда я пытаюсь избавиться от этого сообщения и устанавливаю `eventlet` или `gevent`, то приложение работает перестаёт, а именно - перестают работать `emit'ы`, при этом `@socketio.on("")` отрабатывают.

Проблема встречается, например, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991897/websocket-transport-not-available-install-eventlet-or-gevent-and-gevent-websock), но я не вижу там решения.

Есть идеи?

Comment: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/647

Comment: @Victor VosMottor да, спасибо, эту ссылку я тоже изучал, - приведенный ответ, после которого ишью было помечено, как "closed", мне не помог (см. вторую часть моего вопроса). Там далее по треду идёт разговор об установке .whl, кстати